# Polar coordinates in double integral of two circles

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Use polar coordinates to calculate the integral $\int\int_R(x²+y²)\,dx\,dy$ where $R$ is the region inside $x²-4x+y²=0$ and outside $x²-2x+y²=0$.

This is the graphic of the region: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2E3C.png

I assumed with such information the point $(1,0)$ as the center of the region, but don't know how to set the upper limit of the integral of $r$.

$$2\int_0^\pi\int_1^?r^2*r\, dr\,d\theta$$

What I put in '**?**', or I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer circle is 
\begin{equation}
r=4\cos \theta 
\end{equation}

and the inner circle is

\begin{equation}
r=2\cos \theta 
\end{equation}

so the integral is

\begin{equation}
2\int _{0}^{\pi/2}\int _{2\cos \theta }^{4\cos \theta}r^{3}drd\theta  
\end{equation}

Note: symmetry allows you to integrate from $0$ to $\pi /2$ and multiply the result by $2$

Comment: why $\pi/2$ and not $\pi$? It's a semicircle

Comment: If you look at the graph you should notice that it's entirely on the right of the $y$-axis, or $x \le 0$, or $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like this:

$S = 2\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}  {\int\limits_{ 2\cos (\theta )}^{ 4\cos (\theta )} {{r^3}drd\theta } }$

Answer (score 0):

Do the integral in the outer circle minus the integral in the inner circle! You can use translated polar coordinates for both of them. Let $C_1$ be the outer circle and $C_2$ be the inner circle, that is: $$C_1 : (x-2)^2+y^2 = 4 \\ C_2: (x-1)^2+y^2=1$$So: $$\iint_R x^2+y^2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = \iint_{C_1}x^2+y^2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y - \iint_{C_2}x^2+y^2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y.$$For the first one make $x = 2+r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$, with $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ and $0 < r < 2$.

For the second one make $x = 1+r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$, with $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ and $0 < r < 1$.

Comment: what is $t$ in $x=2+r\ cos\ t$?

Comment: I meant $\theta$, sorry. I originally thought with $t$, but everyone learning the subject sticks with $\theta$, so I went to fix stuff. Forgot one. Just a variable, though..